# Can we move forward and backward with GSV api in python

Tags: python, google-street-view

In Google street view, we'll move forward and backward with the help of arrows

By the help of arrows, we'll move to new co ordinates.

Can we implement that in python?

I'm using [google-streetview](https://pypi.org/project/google-streetview/) api for python. I couldn't find a feature/function for that.

Is there an option/way to do that?

Comment: You could search for a photo that is 20 meters away from your original coordinates. I've seen both closer and farther than 20 meters though. :/

Comment: Means, how does the co ordinates vary? Could you please tell?

Comment: Also @doneforaiur how can we know whether there is turn in streets with this ?

Comment: Think of a circle of 20 meters in diameter. You'd get mostly the same images but each unique image is a either forward or backward from the original coordinates. On a straight road, there would be 2 unique images. However you can't get exact coordinates with this method. Is there any location data in the `metadata` files?

Comment: Metadata : [{"copyright": "\u00a9 Google", "date": "2022-12", "location": {"lat": 11.33340367280061, "lng": 77.71874922870613}, "pano_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "status": "OK", "_file": "gsv_0.jpg"}].  @doneforaiur

Comment: Is the "lat" value and the "lng" value exactly the same as yours, or are they slightly different?

Comment: @doneforaiur same as mine in fact with more precision

Comment: This is pretty tricky, but interesting at the same time. You would need to be wary of the header values also. What have you tried so far?

Comment: How far do you want to move?  Also what directions?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex, move forward and backward as we do in GSV

Comment: @StackOverflow the short answer is no. This is because the API that you're using makes calls to a [non-interactive Street View panorama](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview). There might be a work around, but I need to know how you're using the images that you're ingesting from the API. I also need to know how you want to use the move feature in your program.

Comment: Totally agree with @Lifeiscomplex here. I believe this would cost alot. Since you would have to request for a new image every move, and I guess you would have to also geocode each move. Do you really need to work on this using python? I think it would be nice if you can also like load an embedded javascript streetview with webview in python.

Answer (score 3):

The [google-streetview](https://pypi.org/project/google-streetview/) API that you are using relies on the [Google Street View Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview).

The Google API does this:

> Embed a non-interactive Street View panorama or thumbnail into your web page using a simple HTTP request, with no need for any other code.

Since this API is ***non-interactive*** you cannot move forward or backward as you can in [Google Street View](https://www.google.com/streetview/).

If your use case requires you to move forward or backwards then you should explore using the [Javascript version of Street View](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview).

> Add an interactive Street View panorama to your map using the Maps JavaScript API Street View service.